# os 10.11.6 pip install permission error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am a CS beginner taking udemy python course and trying to install pip in order to use matplotlib, pandas and so on in pylab.

I use IDLE 3.4.2 and latest version Pycharm

Tried
1. "pip installed pylab"(version not satisfies  the requirement pylab,no matching distribution found for pylab);
2.same result with sudo before the first one;
3.sudo easy_install matplotlib（succeeded in terminal, but still no matplotlib module in shell) ;
4.brew install python 3(succeeded , but still no matplotlib module in shell, and every command looks like still for 2.7)
5.Anaconda Package based on preinstalling Macports (same result as 3)
6.On cloud9.io, still can't import matplotlib

Then tried to uninstall both 2 and 3 python then install
7.brew rm -rf/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
(error:no keg argument)

Downloaded Xcode but "block compressed payload operation failed"

Result of "brew doctor":
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4m-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin

Thanks for reading!

Answer in detailed direction will be appreciated as I am just a beginner having tons of stuff to learn from you.

Really frustrated by now.

Comment: Use virtualenv (or virtualenvwrapper)

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py' T-T

Comment: http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html

Comment: I did but errno 13

Comment: The `PATH` warning could be the root cause here.  Try with `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` at the Bash prompt.  If it helps, see if you can figure out how to make the change permanent.  IIRC this was a problem with earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: Also FWIW OS X is not Linux; edited out the [tag:linux] tag.